# OpenCV - Error in Linux but works in Windows

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I am getting the following error when I run this file in Linux. But the same code works in Windows with OpenCV 2.4.11

```
 OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /home/travis/miniconda/conda-bld/work/opencv-2.4.11/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3739
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testImplementation.py", line 206, in <module>
    GestureDemo().run()
  File "testImplementation.py", line 200, in run
    super(GestureDemo, self).run()
  File "/home/kathirdrone/Desktop/ARDRONE /GestureDetection/GestureDetection/current_src/eventBasedAnimationClass.py", line 47, in run
    self.onTimerFiredWrapper()
  File "/home/kathirdrone/Desktop/ARDRONE /GestureDetection/GestureDetection/current_src/eventBasedAnimationClass.py", line 30, in onTimerFiredWrapper
    self.onTimerFired()
  File "testImplementation.py", line 125, in onTimerFired
    self.gp.process()
  File "/home/kathirdrone/Desktop/ARDRONE /GestureDetection/GestureDetection/current_src/GesturesApi.py", line 297, in process
    self.threshold()
  File "/home/kathirdrone/Desktop/ARDRONE /GestureDetection/GestureDetection/current_src/GesturesApi.py", line 111, in threshold
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(self.original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /home/travis/miniconda/conda-bld/work/opencv-2.4.11/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

Any clue to fix this ?

Comment: `self.original` is not a 3 or 4 channel image. Print its `shape` to convince yourself

Comment: can you show the line where the error is caused...??